# Test Automation Framework and reporting

Tags: automation, software-testing, unit-tests, requirements-management

I am searching for a test automation framework that enables integration between my code and functional requirement.

In my automated test script, I am going to annotate associated functional requirements in appropriate code blocks. At the end, I am expecting to see a report showing me the results and their associated functional requirements.

Is that possible with any automation tool ?

Thanks.